# Play icon appearing inconsistently on user avatar

Tags: bug, profile-page, images

On this user avatar on [their user page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8834323/zirr) I see a play icon:

> [image: Screenshot from user page]

But the play-icon disappears from their user card on [one of their questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50561823/):

> [image: From user post]

Comment: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Lfawr1IM9PU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAEHI/fuhBDkwXvXo/photo.jpg?sz=328 this is source

Comment: Try [this](http://www.pmslweb.com/the-blog/lol-pics-your-weekend-collection-of-funny-pictures/4-mom-trying-to-click-play-fail/) one ;)

Comment: Still nothing explain the disparition of the play sign in the question linked

Comment: GIF support fail?

Comment: I think gifs are not supported - have you ever seen an animated avatar?

Comment: Related on MSE: [Animated gifs are animating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239062)

Comment: In the iOS app, on that question, the avatar has the play icon but not in the mobile web version.

Comment: @AndrewT. haha, [Marc is a prophet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239035/animated-gifs-are-animating/239062#comment783547_239062)

Comment: @ryanyuyu that was an epic slow payoff, but... yeah, that